# SQL to select max date from table with only 1 date

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have this SQL code:

```
SELECT MH.[PM#], 
       MH.[Work Done], 
       MH.[Date Done], 
       MH.Comments, 
       MH.[SEM Completed by]
 FROM [Maintenance History tbl] AS MH
WHERE (((MH.[Work Done])="LT") 
  AND ((MH.[Date Done]) =
        ( SELECT Max(MH2.[Date Done])
            FROM [Maintenance History tbl] AS MH2
           WHERE MH2.[PM#] = MH.[PM#]
        )
      ));
```

This selects the four fields where the date done is the most recent.

This does not work if there is only 1 row.

How can I make this return the Max date if there is only 1 row?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Your code works -- event for "PM"s that have only one date. The problem is, it doesn't do what you want. Our problem is that you haven't explained what you want it to do. Sample data and desired results would really help. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have missed the filtering condition `Work Done = "LT"` inside the subquery. Try adding it as in:

```
SELECT MH.[PM#], 
       MH.[Work Done], 
       MH.[Date Done], 
       MH.Comments, 
       MH.[SEM Completed by]
 FROM [Maintenance History tbl] AS MH
WHERE (MH.[Work Done] = "LT"
  AND (MH.[Date Done] =
        ( SELECT Max(MH2.[Date Done])
            FROM [Maintenance History tbl] AS MH2
           WHERE MH2.[PM#] = MH.[PM#]
             and MH2.[Work Done] = "LT"
        )
      ));
```